# What's up with Star Man's Roadster's suspension?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

On Earth, a vehicle's weight compresses the suspension, and the wheel rims are generally designed to closely fit the contour of the tires with only a small gap between.  Take away that weight, the suspension expands and the wheel and rim have a gap between them.  This is particularly displayed when a vehicle is on a lift rack getting its tires changed or rotated, as in this picture.  The eye quickly notices that the two curves do not match up as intended.

[image]

Now we move on to Star Man and his Roadster on their billion year journey around the sun.  In this cropped close-up, this gap does not seem to be happening as one would expect.

[image]

As I understand, the payload adapter is connected to the frame of the roadster, not the wheels, thus the wheels should be free to move under influence of the suspension.  On the Earth-bound lift rack, there is 1G pulling the wheels down, so perhaps the gap will not be as large.  However, the wheels are not supporting any "weight" so the suspension should have moved them at least a little.

The only guesses I have are either that the wheels were "pinned" in some way to prevent bounce during launch, and/or that the fluid was drained from the shocks and struts for safety reasons.

Has this ever been discussed by SpaceX or Tesla?

Comment: I think it's very likely that a lot of things were welded down and otherwise altered on the Roadster, and that it was entirely empty of fluids. That said, the vertical play of the Tesla Roadster suspension is probably quite a bit smaller than that of the car in your first picture.

Comment: In your first picture gravity will be pulling the wheel down.

Comment: The roadster is a modified Lotus.  I have witnessed the same model Lotus merging on to a interstate once and the driver floored it.  That car didn't dip at all under the acceleration.  It was like it was driving on glass rails.  It could be the suspension just doesn't allow much travel to start with.

Comment: With no load on the wheels, the springs would drive them to their bottom-most stops. So either the suspension has very short travel, or the suspension was rigged in some way to keep them at the positions as seen; it's possible this would have been done for aesthetics, since the whole payload was fitted with cameras and at least the one wheel is  in-frame